A UTF-8 text file is failing to import via pandas with a UTF-8 encoding error
I've got a text file exported from SQL as UTF-8 with about 5.5 million rows. I'm trying to then read this file with Pandas/Python, but getting
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 135596: invalid continuation byte

How can I troubleshoot this? I loaded the file into Notepad++ and tried "Convert to UTF-8", but I got the same results. I tried stepping through with a debugger, but pandas is parsing in quite large chunks and I'm having trouble identifying exactly which character is causing it to choke. I tried reading the file as binary and inspecting position 135596 but I didn't see anything out of the ordinary.
Any suggestions on how to identify the issue in our data? At this point I'm considering doing a binary split search (split the data in half, identify which half gives an error, and keep splitting that way until I find it), but it's quite a lot of text.

What version of python are you using?

Try iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 your-file, are there any errors reported? Also try going to position 135596 and then back until you see an ASCII character (such as newline). You can start decoding from that position. See if the error persists.

We can’t tell you the correct encoding without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Thanks, unfortunately the original data contained sensitive information. It was too difficult for me to nail down the exact character... in fact when I read it as binary and inspected the offending position, there didn't seem to be any untoward characters that would cause these issues... however, as mentioned in my answer, the issue seems to have been when exporting the data with SSIS. It claimed to be UTF-8, but there was obviously something wrong. Exporting as UTF-16, then translating to UTF-8 actually solved the issue.

Not sure what the issue was really, but it seems to have been a problem with how SSIS was exporting the data, even when specifying UTF-8. We ended up specifying a different encoding for export, then using Notepad++ of all things to convert it to UTF-8 afterwards, and that fixed the issue.

SSIS doesn't have issues with UTF8. If you have problems, it's because the wrong codepage was used, ie not 65001. How did you export the data? This isn't explained anywhere. Did you use a Flat file destination? Excel destination?

I didn't do the export, but I reviewed with my colleague and verified codepage 65001 was used. It was a flat file destination.

Exporting as UTF-16 you don't have to convert that file to UTF8. use read_csv with encoding='utf16

The program we were using to read the file is not open source, and I didn't have the ability to change any of the arguments to read_csv. I just knew from error logs that it was most likely using read_csv, and the documentation required UTF-8. Hence I was trying to use pandas to debug.
Anyway, I can't justify asking my coworker to give me the exact parameters (beyond the codepage and the destination) of his export to dig deeper since the issue is already solved on our end.

What's the character that causes the problem? Anything unusual like emojis or surrogate pairs? SSIS has no problem with UTF8, that isn't a matter of debate. BUT Unicode has unusual characters that may choke older Linux versions. That's how we found years ago that old Debian versions couldn't handle . And how management was persuaded to finally upgrade

If that's the case, it's no wonder converting to UTF8 in Notepad++ didn't work. The file was already valid UTF8. The manual conversion worked because Notepad++ used different combinations than those used by SSIS. Both results are valid, but the target application can't handle both of them

Yeah I tried reading the bytes in a little before and after the offending position, and printing them out, but the output was exceedingly unremarkable. I think a paranthesis was the only non alpha-numeric character, no accents or anything (and I was expecting to see an í, it's quite possible I was doing this part wrong also)

Accents are trivial. Most accented characters are individual characters. Diacritics can be combined with other characters but that's also pretty common. There are characters like invisible or non-breaking spaces though, half spaces, and even full-/half- width numbers, letters, dots and parentheses even in the plain-vanilla Basic plane that all OSs support all the way back to the 1990s.

If you found out what's wrong, (and still care) you could use the Script component to create a C# source that normalizes the text values before writing them with String.Normalize. You could check what happens by using a diff tool like WinMerge in binary mode to compare the UTF8 files before and after Notepad++

It's likely just an error in the database, if the rest of the file is fine.  You can use code like the following to see what the bad character might be:
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name(b'\xed'.decode('cp1252'))   # decode with common encodings.
'LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE'
>>> ud.name(b'\xed'.decode('latin1'))
'LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE'
>>> print(b'\xed'.decode('latin1'))
í

Here's a demo of reading the bad portion.  Perhaps one entry in the database was written with the wrong encoding:
# Write a simple file with the same error
with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='Windows-1252') as f:
    f.write('Haz clic en el ícono de Explorador.')

# Attempt to read
with open('test.csv', encoding='utf8') as f:
    try:
        f.read()
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        print(e)

# Open in binary mode and seek to a few bytes before
# the error and read a few bytes past.
bad = 15  # location of error
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(bad - 5)
    print(f.read(10))

# Workaround - replace errors
with open('test.csv', encoding='utf8', errors='replace') as f:
    print(f.read())

Output.  Here you can see the \xedicono might be the Spanish word ícono (icon):
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 15: invalid continuation byte
b'n el \xedcono'
Haz clic en el �cono de Explorador.

Pandas can replace errors too:
>>> pd.read_csv('test.csv', encoding_errors='replace')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Haz clic en el �cono de Explorador.]
Index: []


You could solve that problem using the chardet library to identify the encoding of your file and then open it according to that, if it is a bad formed row, the culprit line could be detected with on_bad_lines option or if it is an encoding error, could be treated using the option encoding_errors (for further reference here the official docs). Here an example
import chardet
import pandas as pd
import sys

try:
    #detect the encoding of the file
    with open('your_file.csv', 'rb') as f: #rb = read binary
        result = chardet.detect(f.read())
    #read the file with the encoding detected
    df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', on_bad_lines='warn'
                 #bad characters are replaced with a question mark
                 , encoding=result['encoding'], encoding_errors='replace') 
    # additonal code to process the dataframe
except:    
    print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0], ", exception instance: "
          , sys.exc_info()[1], ", line: ", sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno)


With the error occurring so far into the file, it's much more likely to be a data corruption than a mistaken encoding.

on_bad_lines='warn' warns of too many fields, not bad encoding.  This will still raise a UnicodeDecodeError.

@MarkTolonen You're right, answer edited accordingly.
